# Mail UIActivityViewController not dismissing

Tags: ios

I have a UIActivityViewController which won't dismiss the Mail dialog on the iPad. The code is standard from an Apple example and it works fine on the iPhone.

```
   NSString* someText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Is really cool, sent from Element Story. en.wikipedia.info/wiki/%@",
                          [_detailItem description], [_detailItem description]];

   ActivityViewCustomProvider *customProvider =
    [[ActivityViewCustomProvider alloc]init];

    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:customProvider,imageView.image,someText, nil];

    //ActivityViewCustomActivity *ca = [[ActivityViewCustomActivity alloc]init];


    // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
                                      //applicationActivities:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ca]];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: Please show you code even if it is standard. It will help us diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are displaying this from a splitviewcontroller and that's a problem I've run into as well. Essentially you will need to present the UIActivityViewController from the main view.

so rather than

```
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

something like:

`[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];`

Unfortunately it doesn't look quite as good because it'll show the options throughout the entire view and not just in the context of the navigation side or the details side but it'll work.

Comment: Well, that sucks. Thanks Apple. Great explanation, maybe we will figure this out otherwise.

Comment: Is there a way to just dismiss the mail controller for like when you dismiss the mail controller, the activity selector still stays there?

Comment: You know there may be. I bet you can plug into its completion handler: UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler and just do a [self dismissViewController....]; Unfortunately there is no perfect solution because essentially Apple is already doing that but its doing it to the wrong viewcontroller but I bet you could use that to find a solution.